# ProgressBar no se actualiza al hacer popBackStack()

Tags: java, android

Estoy usando fragments y un Navigation Component. En el onCreateView del fragment "etapas", tengo un metodo que rellena el progreso de las `progressBar`, y tambíen muestra el progreso en un `TextView`. Cuando yo navego a ese fragmento con `Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.etapas);` funciona bien porque tanto el progreso en el `TextView` como en el `ProgressBar` se actualiza. Pero cuando yo vuelvo a ese fragmento ya sea aprentando el BACK del dispositivo o llamando a `Navigation.findNavController(view).popBackStack();` se actualiza el progreso en el `TextView` pero no en el progressBar, este no incrementa.

La diferencia es que cuando carga es que entré con `navigate` pero no me carga cuando vuelvo con `popBackStack()`. Lo más raro es que el textView si carga, asi que no tengo ni la menor idea de porque pasa esto.

Muestro a continuación la navegación:

[image]
1.`Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.etapas);` Si observan el TextView que aparace en todas las etapas dice 0/12. Ahora entro en la etapa 1.
[image]
2. `Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.niveles);`Elijo el nivel 1.
[image]
3. `Navigation.findNavController(view).popBackStack();` Resuelvo el nivel 1 y vuelvo para atras.
[image]
4. `Navigation.findNavController(view).popBackStack();` Vuelvo para atrás nuevamente para ir hacia el menu de etapas.
[image]
Ahora estoy en el menu de etapas, y como se ve en la foto, se incremento el textView (1/12), pero el progressBar está en 0/12.
[image]
5. `Navigation.findNavController(view).popBackStack();` Vuelvo a la pantalla principal
[image]
6. `Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.etapas);` Ahora voy al menu de etapas y pueden ver que el progressBar ya tiene el progreso en (1/12) (Recuerden que esta vez voy con `navigate`).
[image]

Alguien sabe porque pasa esto y como lo puedo solucionar? Mi idea es no usar el `navigate` para volver porque altero la pila y despues no vuelve como quiero cuando presiona BACK. Desde ya gracias.

EDIT: Agrego el codigo que llena los progress y textViews

```
private void verificAssistant(int stage, int startLvl, int endLvl){

    boolean booleans [] = {etapa1_encontrada, etapa2_encontrada, etapa3_encontrada, etapa4_encontrada,
                           etapa5_encontrada, etapa6_encontrada, etapa7_encontrada, etapa8_encontrada,
                           etapa9_encontrada, etapa10_encontrada, etapa11_encontrada, etapa12_encontrada};

    if (!booleans[stage -1]){
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(getContext(), "db", null, version_db);
        SQLiteDatabase db = admin.getWritableDatabase();

        int nivel_etapa = 0;

        while (startLvl <= endLvl){
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT nivel FROM nivel WHERE nivel =" + startLvl, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                nivel_etapa++;
            }
            startLvl++;
        }

        TextView tvs [] = {tv_progress_1, tv_progress_2, tv_progress_3, tv_progress_4, tv_progress_5, tv_progress_6,
                           tv_progress_7, tv_progress_8, tv_progress_9, tv_progress_10, tv_progress_11, tv_progress_12};

        ProgressBar bars [] = {pb_etapa1, pb_etapa2, pb_etapa3, pb_etapa4, pb_etapa5, pb_etapa6,
                               pb_etapa7, pb_etapa8, pb_etapa9, pb_etapa10, pb_etapa11, pb_etapa12};

        tvs[stage -1].setText(nivel_etapa + "/12 "); 
        bars[stage -1].setProgress(nivel_etapa); 

        if (nivel_etapa == 12){
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("etapa", stage);
            db.insert("etapa", null, values);
            comprobar_etapa();
        }

        db.close();
    }
```

Y entonces en el onCreate llamo a ese metodo y le paso los datos de la etapa para que llene su barra y textView de esta forma (Ejemplo con la etapa 1) `verificAssistant(1, 1,  12);`

Comment: Comparte tu código para poder ayudarte, a ver cómo se está seteando el valor en la ProgressBar y cómo se hace en el TextView.

Comment: @ManuelMato ahí agregué el código que uso para poner el progreso en los TextView y en los ProgressBar

Comment: Teniendo en cuenta el ciclo de vida del Fragment, cuando haces popBackStack(), la vista anterior se vuelve a crear, es decir, se llama a onCreateView() pero no al método onCreate() que es dónde ejecutas el método verificAssistant()... por lo que me parece más raro que se actualice el textView a que no se actualice el progress bar, que es lo normal... no sé si falta código o se me está escapando algo, pero prueba a ejecutar el método en el onCreateView().  Ahí deberia actualizar ambas vistas ya que el onViewCreated() la infla y el onCreateView() las setea.

Comment: No se si me expresé mal en la pregunta, pero ahí es donde los ejecuto, en el onCreateView(), es muy raro, gracias por tu ayuda igual. Si queres respondeme eso que te la voto bien.